# Windows 10 sublimelinter-php

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I just upgraded to windows 10 and I cannot get my sublimelinter-php. I have sublimelinter-css and sublimelinter-jshist working fine.

My php file is located in. `C:\xampp\php\php.exe`

My paths look like this atm:

```
        "paths": {
        "linux": [],
        "osx": [],
        "windows": [
            "C:\\xampp\\php\\"
        ]
    },
```

I have tried using the path `C:/xampp/php/`

I have checked that sublimelinter-php is enabled.

I have succesfully been able to use the path `C:\\xampp\\php\\` on my Windows 7 laptop, but can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong now on my Windows 10 version. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have to add `php.exe` to the end of your path.

Comment: Tried and didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up finding the solution by taking a different approach, but before that try running Sublime as admin.

I added the file path `C:\xampp\php` to my computers `PATH environment variable`.

This is done by:
 
1) Going to your PC's `Control Panel`.
2) Select `System`.
3) Select `Advanced system settings`.
4) From System Properties, select `Environment Variables`.
5) Under System Variables find the variable `Path`. Select it and click `edit`.
6) At the end of the Variable Value add your PHP's path location. In my case it was `C:\xampp\php`. All paths are separated by a `;` so be sure to add one, if there isn't already, followed by your PHP's file path.
7) Restart your Sublime Text editor and your sublimelinter-php should be working.

Hopefully that might help someone in the future.